# Geoprocessing Service jobs fails with no errors

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-service

I have a geoprocessing arcpy script that seems to work fine through arcgis client.  I receive no publishing errors.  Whenever I submit a job to the geoprocessing service, it fails almost instantly.  The job details all look similar to the following:

```
Job Details: j0191703c856e42d2a5e3c830fc9a6175 (MarketAnalysis)
Job ID: j0191703c856e42d2a5e3c830fc9a6175

Job Status: esriJobFailed

Job Messages:

    esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Submitted.
    esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing...
    esriJobMessageTypeError: Failed.
```

The problem is that nothing shows up in any logs even with it set to debug.  I have some logging at the very start of my script and it appears to fail before that.  The best I can figure is that it fails before executing the script, but I can't verify that.  I don't knwo where else to look.  All that I can see is the status of 'esriJobMessageTypeError', but no cause as to why.

Has anyone seen this?  Does anyone know anyway to determine the problem?  Other geoprocessing services work, just not this one.

Comment: You need to through some comments/logging into your script at a finer level, so you can see responses as it start to spin up. I setup messages when my Temp/Scratch space is set then as I select my layers etc. This lets me see where/when events are triggering or failing. You can throw a Try/Catch around events to focus the process too.

Comment: That, but more importantly, he needs to turn messages to INFO on the Parameters page of the GP Service. That will start spitting out more relevant information which you've trapped/expressed in the script. Right now you have it set to None.

Comment: @D.E.Wright, I placed error logs at the very start of my script and they aren't happening.  I don't think my script is being run.

Comment: @KHibma, thank you for the suggestion about INFO on the parameters page.  I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Ah! A perfect failure!

Comment: @KHibma, I set messages to INFO and unfortunately no help there either.  Gremlins perhaps?

Comment: With message level set to INFO, you should follow DEWright's suggestion and put some AddMessages or TRY/EXCEPTs in. If you dont see these messages then make sure you've set messages on the service itself, not messages in the Logs (which are unrelated)

Comment: @KHibma, Sorry for not being more clear.  I put both `AddError` and `AddMessage` as the first part of my script:

    # Esri start of added imports
    import sys, os, arcpy
    # Esri end of added imports
    arcpy.AddError('starting')
    arcpy.AddMessage('starting')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out the real problem of the missing error messages.  While talking to a coworker about the problem he mentioned that in 10.1sp1 (and I guess 10.2 as well) there is a bug related to generating a SD from geoprocessing results.  You must chose a connection.  I wasn't doing this.  After including a connection, I am now seeing errors in the logs related to problems with the script.  I assume the failures I was seeing were related to the missing connection.